# Routing Rules are Conflicting

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

My applications Routing url is like:

```
routes.Add("Rule1",
            new Route("test/12345/{subjectname}/{pageno}",
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
            new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test.aspx")));

   routes.Add("Rule2",
                new Route("questions/middle-east/{subjectname}/{pageno}",
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
                new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test.aspx")));

        routes.Add("Rule3",
               new Route("questions/universal-affairs/{subjectname}/{topicname}/{pageno}",
               new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
               new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
               new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test.aspx")));


        routes.Add("Rule4", new Route("questions/{subjectname}/recent-questions/{pageno}",
              new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
              new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
              new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test1.aspx")));

    routes.Add("Rule5", new Route("questions/{subjectname}/{topicname}/recent-questions/{pageno}",
              new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
              new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
              new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test2.aspx")));

    routes.Add("Rule6", new Route("questions/{subjectname}/{topicname}/{subtopicname}/recent-questions/{pageno}",
                   new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
                   new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
        new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test3.aspx")));


    routes.Add("Rule7", new Route("questions/{subjectname}/recent-questions/{pageno}",
                   new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
                   new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
        new GlobalURLRouteHandler("~/test/test3.aspx")));
```

These are my existing url now I want to replace **/ with -** in these url's, when I have did this my URL are conflicting.

Can anyone suggest me how can do this and how can get the values of variable.

Comment: 'Conflicting' and 'not getting any value' are not exactly the same. Can you describe the result (problem) better and post one of the new rules as well?

Comment: i get the same issue somedays ago, i just wrote all of my route from bottom to top. That's because it is override by the top route. So, i suggest to write your routes from bottom to top i mean rule 5 shoult be at top, after that route 4 ....

Comment: That extra rule doesn't appear to be very different. Also make it a separate code block and do point the differences. Which `/` do you want to replace?

Comment: make your routes from bottom to top ie. 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong: what you want is to declare your route to be something like "test-12345-{subjectname}-{pageno}" ?

Comment: My rule will be questions/{subjectname}-{topicname}-recent-questions-{pageno}